# How can I use char[] in C++ to string in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I want something like:

```
    _declspec(dllexport) int Test(char data[])
```

How can I replace ??? in C# (code below):

```
    [DllImport("dllname.dll")]
    static extern int Test(??? data)
```

Can I use `string` as the replacement of `???` ? Thanks.

```
declspec(dllexport) int Test(char data[])
[DllImport("dllname.dll")]
static extern int Test(??? data)
```

Comment: C# uses Unicode strings (UTF-16), `char` is 8 bits in MSVC++. What encoding conversion do you need? `DllImport` can't guess that.

Comment: If you want to use string then declare the function correctly, the argument should be `const char*`.